Converting single-phase 120 VAC to 240
I have an electric vehicle (Rivian R1T) which has an inverter which produces 120 VAC.  The inverter supplies 3 120 VAC outlets, all on the same 15A circuit.
I'm wondering what problems I might encounter using a 1:2 center-tapped transformer to produce 240.  Assuming I could get enough current, I could then run my well-pump in emergencies.  The inverter is rated at 1500W so 240 current would only be ~7A so I'd likely have to deal with the start-up surge.  The pump is a 1/2 HP, 12 gpm Meyers submersible model #3NFL52-12-P4-01.  It is fed through a control box with a 59-71uf capacitor.

Using a 1:2 transformer should work, but you might contact Rivian, with details of the pump make and model, and include starting and running current. To me, it seems damage to the Rivian's inverter is an unlikely, but possibly expensive risk -- I'd go for a separate inverter and battery, and charge it from the Rivian, if need be. That way it would work even when the vehicle is out and about.

Your pump surge is likely to be 500% of rated power

Could you run it off 120VAC in an emergency? Is it water cooled?

@D.A.S.  Yes, it's water-cooled, in that it's a submersible pump.  But how would one run it off 120?  It wouldn't run with only one leg, would it?

120V is Line & Neutral but only 1/4 power and 1/2 Voltage, just a thought
